# Why doesn't the item in the stack get popped off immediately when you return in recursion?

Tags: recursion, stack

Okay, this might be a stupid question. But I thought that whenever you return something, the item in the stack gets popped off. But in case of recursion, the items in the stack keeps piling up until the it reaches the base case. Then it starts to get popped off. I was wondering why that is.

And also, when exactly does an item gets pop off the stack?

Comment: _Which_ item exactly? The current stackframe _does_ get popped from the stack on return, even on recursive function calls.

Comment: It does. But you make recursive calls before you return--that's what makes it recursive.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm going to assume by "item", you're referring to the stack frame of a function [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) rather than an item element in a [stack data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) (which operates like a call stack). I'm hoping to clear up confusion about how the call stack works.*

*Also note that each [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) in a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has its own call stack. For now, assume we're working with a single process that has one running thread of execution.*

---

A recursive function is a function that calls itself. Whenever a function is called, the thread which has reached the function call instruction creates a stack frame. A stack frame is a chunk of memory containing all of the data necessary to execute the called function (variables, parameters, etc). This frame is "pushed" onto the top of the call stack. The currently executing function which is making the call is suspended temporarily and the stack pointer moves up to the new frame, which is then executed.

Without a base case, or conditional state where the function no longer makes recursive calls, the recursion will go on indefinitely. When this happens, the operating system sends a signal to terminate the process when it exceeds its stack usage (typically something like 1 MB).

After reaching the base case and the last line of code in the function is executed, the thread begins resolving stack frames from the top down, popping them off the stack as they finish execution (they might do more work or make additional recursive calls).

A pop amounts to freeing the memory associated with the frame, handling return values, moving the stack pointer back to the caller and resuming execution where the call was made.

Here's a sample program in C, Python and JS containing a recursive function and a diagram:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void count_to(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        count_to(n - 1);
    }

    printf("%d\n", n);
}

int main() {
    count_to(4);
    return 0;
}
```

```py
def count_to(n):
    if n > 0:
        count_to(n - 1)
    
    print(n)

count_to(4)
```

```js
const countTo = n => {
  if (n > 0) {
    countTo(n - 1);
  }

  console.log(n);
};

countTo(4);
```

Here's the output of the program:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Here's what the call stack looks like during execution:

```
[count_to(4)]  <-- top of call stack/stack pointer
[main]         <-- bottom of call stack
```

```
[count_to(3)]  <-- 
[count_to(4)]  
[main]
```

```
[count_to(2)]  <-- 
[count_to(3)]
[count_to(4)]
[main]
```

```
[count_to(1)]  <--
[count_to(2)]
[count_to(3)]
[count_to(4)]
[main]
```

```
[count_to(0)]  <--
[count_to(1)]
[count_to(2)]
[count_to(3)]
[count_to(4)]
[main]
```

At this point, nothing has been printed yet. The thread has just been adding function calls to the stack. But once we call `count_to(0)`, recursion stops. As we pop stack frames, each function will print its local value of `n` and return to its caller.

```
print(0)
return

[count_to(1)]  <-- 
[count_to(2)]
[count_to(3)]
[count_to(4)]
[main]
```

```
print(1)
return

[count_to(2)]  <-- 
[count_to(3)]
[count_to(4)]
[main]
```

```
print(2)
return

[count_to(3)]  <--
[count_to(4)]
[main]
```

```
print(3)
return

[count_to(4)]  <--
[main]
```

```
print(4)
return

[main]         <--
```

At last, execution returns to main, which exits.

This behavior isn't specific to recursion, by the way. Recursion isn't fundamentally any different than a normal series of function calls: each call is made, then popped when a `return` statement is encountered or control flow reaches the end of the function. Control continues on in the calling function and never skips call frames.

---

I recommend reading wikipedia's articles such as [stack-based memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) and [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and writing a lot of miniature recursive programs like the example here to see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
def bar(n):
    if n > 0:
        print(n)
        return bar(n-1)
    return 'end'
```

in `return bar(n-1)` statement, we first execute `bar(n-1)`, and then return `the return value` of `bar(n-1)`.

When we execute `bar(n-1)`, we will meet alike case unless `n > 0` no longer is `True`.

It is why we can have recursion.

Maybe my explanation is bored, I want to share you a [visualized link](http://pythontutor.com/composingprograms.html#code=def%20bar%28n%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3E%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28n%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20bar%28n-1%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'end'%0A%20%20%20%20%0Abar%284%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=0&mode=display&origin=composingprograms.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D), **which you really want to have a look**.